# Rotate line about 2 points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am wrighting some code that requires an equation that allows me to rotate a straight line about 2 coordinate points.

Basically I have a straight line ($y=mx+c$) and when I change variable $A$ the line rotates about the point $(x_1, y_1)$ and when I change variable $B$ the line rotates about point $(x_2, y_2)$.

Thanks for any help.

*edit* A and B are variables adjusted on a slider. They can be angle or a multiplier whichever works best for the experssion. In sumarry increasing A buy a given amount doesnt have to translate to a specific change in the position of the line.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$ ? and rotation by what degree ?

Comment: Exactly, try to be more precise and give us more detail. Remember that in math it doesn't matter how good a question is if the other one can't understand PRECISELY what you mean

Answer (score 0):

[image: Line_rot_1]

Starting from $y=mx+c$ , rewrite it in terms of the dot product with the unit normal vector
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( { - {m \over {\sqrt {1 + m^2 } }}} \right)x + \left( {{1 \over {\sqrt {1 + m^2 } }}} \right)y = {c \over {\sqrt {1 + m^2 } }} = d  \cr 
  & \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & {\bf x} \cdot {\bf n} = d \cr} 
$$

Determine the angle $\alpha$ made by $\bf n$ with the x axis (arctan in four quadrants)
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \cos \alpha  =  - {m \over {\sqrt {1 + m^2 } }} \hfill \cr 
  \sin \alpha  = {1 \over {\sqrt {1 + m^2 } }} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Rewrite the same equation with reference origin translated into $P_1$ and $P2$
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \left( {{\bf x}_1  + {\bf p}_1 } \right) \cdot {\bf n} = d\quad  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf x}_1  \cdot {\bf n} = d - {\bf p}_1  \cdot {\bf n} = d_1  \hfill \cr 
  \left( {{\bf x}_2  + {\bf p}_2 } \right) \cdot {\bf n} = d\quad  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf x}_2  \cdot {\bf n} = d - {\bf p}_2  \cdot {\bf n} = d_2  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Now, when you rotate by an angle $\beta $ the line wrt $P_1$ ,
you take the first expression and change the angle of $\bf n$ while keeping $d_1$ constant
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf x}_1  \cdot \left( {\cos \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right),\sin \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right)} \right) = d_1 \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {{\bf x} - {\bf p}_1 } \right) \cdot \left( {\cos \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right),\sin \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right)} \right) = d_1 \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf x} \cdot \left( {\cos \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right),\sin \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right)} \right) = d - {\bf p}_1  \cdot {\bf n} + {\bf p}_1 \left( {\cos \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right),\sin \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right)} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf x} \cdot {\bf n}\left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right) = d + {\bf p}_1  \cdot \left( {{\bf n}\left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right) - {\bf n}\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$

And similarly for rotating around $P_2$